# jquery fadein and fadeout not working properly

Tags: jquery

here is the script to fadeout text and fadein new text

but one text should completely fadeout and then the newone should fadein slowly, I don't know what's wrong in my code.

```
    var textArray = ["murali","prashanth","nutal","candy"];

    var getRand = (function() {
    var nums = [0,1,2,3];
    var current = [];
    function rand(n) {
        return (Math.random() * n)|0;
    }
    return function() {
      if (!current.length) current = nums.slice();
      return current.splice(rand(current.length), 1);
    }
}());

setInterval(function(){callme();},5000);

function callme(){
    var x = getRand();
    $("#mydiv").html(textArray[x])
    $("#mydiv").fadeOut(4000).fadeIn(2000);
}
```

[**check JSFIDDLE HERE..**](http://jsfiddle.net/M7p3S/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M7p3S/10/)

```
$("#mydiv").fadeIn();
$("#mydiv").fadeOut(3000);
```

I have changed the fadeout and fadein times

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the time you specified

```
 $("#mydiv").fadeOut(4000).fadeIn(4000);
```

specify the same time in both `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`

[**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/M7p3S/8/)

Answer (score 1):

[Check JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/M7p3S/12/)

Fixes are as :

1. Change the SetInterval to total of the animation timeline such that `interval = fadein + fadeout` (6000 = 4000+2000)
2. Change the order of animation and html content setup, i.e.

   1. set html (new content set before we show)
   2. set fade in (new content appears)
   3. set fade out (send back the content fading out)

Check the [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/M7p3S/12/) with the same fade timings as yours with changed internal set to 6000 instead of 5000 and the changed order of animations.

**Working Code:**

```
var textArray = ["murali","prashanth","nutal","candy"];

var getRand = (function() {
    var nums = [0,1,2,3];
    var current = [];
    function rand(n) {
        return (Math.random() * n)|0;
    }
    return function() {
      if (!current.length) current = nums.slice();
      return current.splice(rand(current.length), 1);
    }
}());

setInterval(function(){callme();},6000);

function callme(){
    var x = getRand();
    $("#mydiv").html(textArray[x])
    $("#mydiv").fadeIn(2000)
    $("#mydiv").fadeOut(4000);
}
```